# Find sup, inf, min, max of the set B

Tags: analysis

Given the set $$B=\left\{\frac{1}{n}+(-1)^n, n \in \mathbb N\right\}$$
I have to find $\sup B$, $\inf B$, $\max B$, $\min B$.$$$$
For $n=even:$

$$B_{even}=\left\{\frac{1}{2k}+1, k=1,2,...\right\}$$

For $n=odd:$

$$B_{odd}=\left\{\frac{1}{2k+1}-1, k=0,1,2,...\right\}$$

So, $\max B= 1+ \frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{2}$, $\sup B =\frac{3}{2}$, $\min B=-1$, $\nexists \inf B$. Is this correct?

Comment: There is always a sup and inf, but there is not always a max and min.

Comment: If it is nonempty.

Comment: @vadim123 Oh I meant $\inf B=-1$ and $\nexists \min B$..

Comment: @user117818 Ok! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$B_{even}={\frac{1}{2k}-1, k=1,2,...} $$

$$B_{odd}=\{\frac{1}{2k+1}+1, k=0,1,2,...\}$$

So $\inf B= -1$, $\sup B = \max B = 2$, $\nexists \min B$.

Comment: Oh..I accidentally wrote wrong the set..It's with a $+$ and not with a $-$. I will edit my post.Is there a way to show that $\inf B=-1$??

Comment: Yes, first you can see that $\frac{1}{n}+1 > 0>-1$ for $n$ being odd and $-1 + \frac{1}{n} > -1$ for $n$ being even. Now $\frac{1}{2k}-1$ is a sequence that converges to $-1$, hence there is always  an element of $B$ as close as you want to the rigth to -1.

Comment: Ok!!Thank you very much for your answer!!